# word or concise phrase to mean the opposite of "ongoing"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am building a form in which the user will select one of the following two options; I am looking for a single-word or concise phrase to fill in the blank. The meaning of the word(s) that should go in the blank spot below should be: *the opposite of the word/concept "ongoing."*

- Ongoing exhibition
- ______ exhibition

To define/contextualize the phrase "ongoing exhibition," it is the concept of an exhibition that has a start date, but no end date.

The phrase "______ exhibition" should mean: *an exhibition with a defined start date **and** end date.*

I have considered using the terms "set exhibition" or "defined exhibition" but I find that phrasing to be confusing and awkward.

Comment: You are presumably referring to future exhibitions?

Comment: Not necessarily. The purpose of the form is to catalog any sort of exhibition, whether it occurred in the past, is currently happening, or will occur in the future.

Comment: And with what purpose are the users opting for these exhibitions if they can be past ones?

Comment: to document the fact that the exhibition happened.

Comment: Just bear in mind that "ongoing" does not necessarily mean that the exjibition has no end date.

Comment: In the domain which I am serving, "ongoing" does mean that the exhibition has no end date.

Comment: @sion_corn Then this sounds more like a question of jargon in a particular field, rather than common English usage.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: The *Metropolitan Museum of Art* calls its exhibitions without end dates *ongoing*. [See their webpage](https://www.metmuseum.org/exhibitions). So this is what it means in museum-speak.

Comment: @GArthurBrown you make a fair point. **fev** ended up suggesting the word "temporary", which happens to be the correct jargon term within the context of museums and galleries.

Comment: @PeterShor: this is indeed the context in which I was hoping to find an ideal solution. I ended up going with the word "temporary," which is appropriate museum-speak for what I'm after.

Comment: In American English, *Ongoing Exhibitions* are frequently contrasted with *Special Exhibitions* — with *special* having the meaning you describe: has a shelf life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ***finite***

> *having a limit or end*:
>
> - We only have a ***finite*** amount of time to
>   complete this task - we can't continue indefinitely. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/finite))

But the most common adjective used with exhibition, as this [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A_ADJ%20exhibitions&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsuch_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpublic_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btheatrical_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bannual_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bother_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binternational_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspecial_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdramatic_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btemporary_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvarious_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsuch_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpublic_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btheatrical_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bannual_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bother_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binternational_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspecial_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdramatic_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btemporary_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvarious_ADJ%20exhibitions%3B%2Cc0) shows, is ***[temporary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/temporary-exhibition)*** which means:

> lasting for only a *limited period of time*; not permanent.
> e.g. a temporary job ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=temporary%20meaning&sxsrf=ALeKk00hxiO8SR7FXrmi7nSsUseawNwvOQ%3A1626292381834&ei=nUDvYKC4MpeGhbIP1vqQ-AI&oq=temporary%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIKCAAQsQMQRhD5ATICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoHCAAQRxCwAzoNCAAQsQMQkQIQRhD5AToLCC4QxwEQrwEQkQI6BwgAEIcCEBQ6CAgAELEDEJECSgQIQRgAUJAXWNcdYJMsaAFwAngAgAHEBIgBvwuSAQcwLjcuNS0xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

Here is an explanation about the term:

> In the current communication era where priority is given to the *temporary over the permanent*, museums are increasingly developing ***temporary exhibitions*** and through them the museum is being transformed. (*[Temporary Museum Exhibitions as Tools for Cultural Innovation](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-12453-3_7)*)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhibition) explains that

> In common usage, "exhibitions" are considered ***temporary*** and usually *scheduled to open and close on specific dates*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - upvoted for now. I will wait to see if anyone else can suggest anything.

Comment: "temporary" is the word I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

### Time-limited

> The exhibitions that were included were time-limited, short-term installations, rather than long-term installations or re-installations. ([Source PDF](https://www.si.edu/Content/opanda/docs/Rpts2002/02.08.ExhibitionCaseStudies.Final.pdf))

> On this basis we have created a call out for anyone who would like to submit work for our time-limited exhibition in August 2021. ([Source](https://www.curatorspace.com/opportunities/detail/creative-call-out-play-care-community/5576))

Most exhibitions I’ve seen at galleries or museums are split into “ongoing” and “time-limited”. Usually when the time-limited exhibitions are shown on a website, they aren’t labeled; in place of ‘ongoing’ it says ‘through *date*’.

Comment: Thanks @ColleenV. I ended up going with "temporary" exhibition, as it is a phrase I have heard others use in the gallery/museum context.